# Emulator process for AVD has terminated

Tags: android, mobile, mobile-development

[image]I have created a virtual device in android studio and when launching that VD it just terminates throwing the message " The emulator process for AVD Pixel_*5_*API_23 has terminated".

I deleted the device and created another device, it still shows the same error. I have uninstalled and installed it again (Android Studio) 2,3 times, I have JDK installed, SDK is also installed and the necessary path is also provided.

Comment: where are you running this, Windows, Mac or Linux based?

Comment: i am running this on Window 10

Comment: Do you have sufficient storage space in your HD? Try verify your storage and emulator storage.

Comment: i have enough space in HD for emulator , approx 48GB is left

Comment: try https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline , this way you can see the actual error.

Comment: I have the same issue and I got 122 GB free space, Until now emulator is not working, tried different solution but no luck. But I know I can solve this, looking for another solution

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I installed my windows 11 system as windows PRO N. But windows PRO N means the windows system that does not supports media feature. So, the system didn't support media feature and it was why the error was happened. After installing PRO, It works correctly. Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to add the environment variable ANDROID_SDK_ROOT: in System Properties -> Advance -> Environment Variables then add in System Variables ANDROID_SDK_ROOT and as value your sdk folder route.